# bootstrap4 как блок поместить вниз

Tags: html, bootstrap4

есть такой шаблон. Блок 1111111 находится под вертикальным меню. при сужении окна браузера (адаптивный шаблон) этот блок уходит на самый верх,а как сделать так чтобы она уходил в самый низ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
 <div class="card h-1">
                <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="#">1111111111111</a>
                  </h4>
                  <h5>$24.99</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте встроенный класс **.order**
[Документация Bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order)